# With NextJS, I want to display results only from the server

Tags: next.js

How can I force a refresh if the person navigates here while logged in.  Also, I currently have my data fetching done in getInitialProps but only when req exists (server side). What should I do to make sure if a navigation happens back to this page that it always re-renders server side?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to make `getInitialProps` run only on server side.
From the [docs](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/#fetching-data-and-component-lifecycle)

> For the initial page load, `getInitialProps` will execute on the server only.
>   `getInitialProps` will only be executed on the client when navigating to a
>   different route via the `Link component` or using the routing APIs.

You can use isomorphic [fetch](https://github.com/developit/unfetch/tree/master/packages/isomorphic-unfetch) that exists both on server side and client side so you won't care on what side your data gets fetched. Example with using `fetch` can be found on [docs as well](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/blob/canary/examples/data-fetch/pages/index.js)

Hope this helps!